# Read Java Internet Connections settings - jdk1.4

Tags: java, proxy, connection

Is there a way of getting internet connection settings (proxy information) being used by java to connect to the internet?

With Java 1.5 you can use the [ProxySelector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) introduced then, is there any way of doing it in jdk1.4?

I tried getting these seeting using the following code snippet, but returning nulls even though i have set my proxy.

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
String ip = null;
String port = null;
String noProxyHosts = null;

if (javaVersion.startsWith("1.4")) {
    ip = System.getProperty("proxyHost");
    port = System.getProperty("proxyPort");
    noProxyHosts = System.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts");
} else {
    ip = System.getProperty("deployment.proxy.http.host");
    port = System.getProperty("deployment.proxy.http.port");
    noProxyHosts = System.getProperty("deployment.proxy.override.hosts");
}
```

A brief background; I have a webstart Java application that spawns an internal web browser which needs these setting to get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code sample on the Java forums:

```
  sun.plugin.net.proxy.ProxyInfo pi = sun.plugin.net.proxy.PluginProxyManager.getProxyInfo(url);
  String host = pi.getProxy();
  int port = pi.getPort();
```

You need to add plugin.jar to your classpath to use this code.  I found it in /jre/lib.

The URL to the forum post is: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=364342&forumID=30

Comment: i found the code snippet really helpful. http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=1535962#1535962